# How to determine if a Javascript class has been declared?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that is being referenced via html that is loaded via AJAX (ie: AJAX retrieves HTML, HTML has a `<script>` tag in it that references this javascript)

This javascript contains class declarations, ex:

```
class CalculatorClass{
    ...
}
```

If this script gets loaded twice, I get an error: `redeclaration of let CalculatorClass`.  Since it's not a variable, I can't test if it's `undefined` first - and even then it would restrict the scope.  How do I only declare the class if it isn't already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check if a class is already declared using `if (typeof MyClass === 'function')`

Comment: To build on this you can then define the class globally inside the `if`: `if(typeof MyClass !==' function'){ window.MyClass = class{}}`

Comment: Thanks.  And thanks for the clarifying comment @NickA